# PHP Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered

Tags: hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Can someone help me fix this error?

PHP Notice: wp_enqueue_script was called **incorrectly**. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts` hooks. Please see [Debugging in WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.0.) in /nas/content/live/greattaste/wp-includes/functions.php on line 4986

code:

```
function wp_auth_check_load() {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( defined( 'IFRAME_REQUEST' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $screen = get_current_screen();
    $hidden = array( 'update', 'update-network', 'update-core', 'update-core-network', 'upgrade', 'upgrade-network', 'network' );
    $show   = ! in_array( $screen->id, $hidden );

    /**
     * Filters whether to load the authentication check.
     *
     * Passing a falsey value to the filter will effectively short-circuit
     * loading the authentication check.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     *
     * @param bool      $show   Whether to load the authentication check.
     * @param WP_Screen $screen The current screen object.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'wp_auth_check_load', $show, $screen ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-auth-check' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-auth-check' );

        add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_html', 5 );
        add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_html', 5 );

    }
}
```

Comment: How are you calling `wp_auth_check_load`? Is it attached to a hook? such as `add_action( 'init', 'wp_auth_check_load' );` ?

Comment: It's s big function that contains all these code: 
 function wp_auth_check_load() {.... wp_register_style(..);                  
wp_register_script()                                                  
 }

Comment: @Luis but how are you using that function? In your code how do you call `wp_auth_check_load`

Comment: `wp_auth_check_load` is a function in WP core, are you making edits and modifications to the WP core files?! This is very dangerous, bad practice, and should never be done. All your changes will be lost when you update WordPress. If you want to make changes to WP behaviour or add new functionality, you should use plugins and hooks/filters like everybody else

Answer (score -1):

Before you can use, those two lines :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-auth-check' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-auth-check' );
```

you should register those assets, inside wp_enqueue_scripts or admin_enqueue_scripts, like the following :

```
function my_assets() {
wp_register_style( 'wp-auth-check', 'path/to/style', $deps = array, $ver = false, $media = 'all' )
 wp_register_script( 'wp-auth-check', 'path/to/your-script', $deps = array, $ver = false, $in_footer = false )
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets');
or 
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets');
```

Comment: This still won't work – they need to register _and_ enqueue the scripts after `wp_enqueue_scripts` or `admin_enqueue_scripts`. The `wp_auth_check_load` function is being called before these hooks (hence the error) :)

Comment: This is not the answer, the problem is not what he did, but when/where he did it, like Andy said